# How to NOT blur border edges?

Tags: css, overflow, blur

is it possible to NOT blur the border edges of my blured image when not in hour off?
can overflow fix this. is it possible to apply no effect on bevel edges?

i would be very grateful for any examples or suggestions.

thx yummi

```css
body {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    margin: 50px;
}
    .gallery {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1.22); 
    overflow:hidden;
}
    /*................ bevels ................*/

    img#bevel {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
    /*......... crossfade on buttons .........*/

    #hover img{
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    filter: blur(4px);
}
    a:hover .hover{
    filter: blur(4px);
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    filter: blur(0);
}
    /*............. pop on hover .............*/
    
    #pop img {transition: .5s ease}
    #pop img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" id="pop">
<a id="hover" href="topup.htm"><img src="https://www.wizzfree.com/pix/vid0.jpg" width="100" id="bevel" class="nohover"><class="hover"></a>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>How to NOT blur border edges?</p>
```

Comment: you html is invalid at `<class="hover"></a>`

Comment: thx but can you fix this first?

Comment: i updated answer :) if any  change i wolud happly change the answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
instead of `img:hover` use `.gallery:hover`

```
.gallery:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.35);
  transform: scale(1.35);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  margin: 50px;
  position:relative;
}
.gallery {
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  right:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform: scale(1.22); 
  border-radius: 20px;
  -o-transition:.3s;
  -ms-transition:.3s;
  -moz-transition:.3s;
  -webkit-transition:.3s;
}

.nohover{
  filter: blur(4px);
}
a:hover .hover{
  filter: blur(4px);
}
a:hover .nohover{
  filter: blur(0);
}

.gallery:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.35);
  transform: scale(1.35);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" id="pop">
    <a id="hover" href="topup.htm">
        <img src="https://www.wizzfree.com/pix/vid0.jpg" width="200" id="bevel" class="nohover" />
    </a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>How to NOT blur border edges?</p>
```

Comment: Are you want like this ?

Comment: the border edges in the blur, should not be blured!

Comment: is the top edges ?

Comment: try now :) i updated answer . you can remove the overflow:hidden to make blured edge.

Comment: ray, they are still blured? example image here: url https://www.wizzfree.com/pix/screen.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer is correct. Don't forgot [to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) btw Thanks :)

Comment: Are you want something like this?